# Train speed and closed windows

Tags: classical-mechanics, speed

Most coaches in Indian trains are non-air-conditioned, i.e., the windows can be opened. Recently, the government has planned to convert all coaches in some trains to A.C., citing the fact [1](https://www.google.com/amp/s/m.hindustantimes.com/india-news/railways-to-upgrade-high-speed-trains-with-only-special-ac-coaches/story-8bwzyJs7h3ODBTqS9BGTrO_amp.html) that for trains to achieve a certain speed (130 km/hr), the windows *must* remain closed.

Specifically, they have made the following claim: 
"AC coaches become a technical necessity wherever the speed of the train is going to be above 130 km/hr."

How true is this claim? The trains with 110km/hr and below will still have non-A.C. coaches.

Answer (score 3):

I am speculating here:

The reason would stem from the fact that driving at that speed with all windows open will result in a “parachute” effect. That is, the fact that all the windows are open will require more energy for the train to reach this speed.

And if this much energy is being expended, it probably will cost as much, if not less, to install air conditioning (if it means closing all the windows). That is, using the lost energy/cost in drag, this can go to air conditioning.

This will result in less power costs and comfortable passengers is another benefit.

Comment: This is correct.  There have been tests on consumer automobiles (USA) which show the energy cost of running A/C is generally less than the drag-energy cost of leaving windows open at highway speeds.

Comment: Thanks @CarlWitthoft I really was speculating!